# Rails validation for web address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, url, model

On my website, users have an option to fill in their website. To keep it simple, I would like to let them to fill in their URL address like `website.com` or `www.website.com`. Is there any trick or helper to set up this validation rule in model?

Comment: without `http/https`?

Comment: Yes, without protocols.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [activevalidators](https://github.com/franckverrot/activevalidators), which provides several validation helpers.

Which will make your validation the following :

```
validates :url, :url   => true
```

[what it does](https://github.com/franckverrot/activevalidators/blob/master/lib/active_model/validations/url_validator.rb) is use the internal URI api, which contains a [regex matching uris](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-regexp), and matches the field's value against it.

Comment: Thank you Damien for this advise, but when I try it, I got this error: `Unknown validator: 'UrlValidator'` -> do I need to include any library or something like that?

Comment: Have you added the gem to your Gemfile ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it with using regex:

```
  validates :url, :presence => {:message => 'URL cannot be blank.'}, :format => {:with => /\A[www]+[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => 'INCORRECT FORMAT!'}
```